# “Einstein ketzos”

Tags: halacha-theory, torah-study, lomdus, maseches-kiddushin

Shalom chevra, I have heard that the ketzos hachoshen on the sugya of matana al menas lehachzir is called the “Einstein ketzos”. If someone knows why that is, and can let us know that would be great!

Comment: Do you know who calls it that? I recall learning such a ketzos and no one I know called it that.

Comment: I was speaking to a bachur in ponevezh who told me that. And a few bachrim from other yeshivas also, so I’m assuming it’s yadua in the velt